# Is repository pattern only to be used with Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ado.net, entity-framework-5

I have been using `Entity Framework` and the `repository pattern` for some time now.

I was asked the other day to write a data layer without using Entity Framework, just plain old `ADO.NET`.  I was wondering what would be the best approach for this? Do I also use a repository pattern for my CRUD operations using plain old ADO.NET?

If I go to `Codeplex` and search for repository pattern then 99.9% of all the sample projects use Entity Framework.  Is there a different pattern that needs to be used if I use plain ADO.NET with stored procedures?

Comment: NO, definitely not. The repository pattern is a general-purpose pattern for data access - it can be used any time you access data - no matter *how* exactly you access the data.

Comment: In fact, the entire *point* of using the repository pattern is to isolate your application from how you access the data. That it frequently is EF is either a testament to how useful that framework is, or to the dearth of alternatives in dotnetland.

Answer (score 4):

No, the repository pattern is used extensively outside of the Entity Framework, and is an all round useful way of handling data access.

*From MSDN*

- It centralizes the data logic or Web service access logic.
- It provides a substitution point for the unit tests.
- It provides a flexible architecture that can be adapted as the overall design of the application evolves.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx

Other benefits:

- Simple to add logic in the repository, such as caching results over a web request
- Common query's can be added, such as `userRepository.FindByEmailAddress(emailAddress);`
- Repository can be changed out with another, such as switching a dabase to a web service with minimal effort

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is the right way. But there are some assumptions

Adding a Repository pattern on top of EF code. This keep distances you from the features of your ORM. The Entity Framework is already an abstraction layer over your database.

If you want to use the Dependency Injection and Test Driven Development over EF then you follow the Repository Pattern. By using RP your code become testable and Injectable / maintainable.

Out of the box EF is not very testable, but it's quite easy to make a mockable version of the EF data context with an interface that can be injected.

If we don’t want our code to be testable or injectable then just don’t use RP.

I saw a blog post: http://www.nogginbox.co.uk/blog/do-we-need-the-repository-pattern

Comment: But did you see this post? http://www.sapiensworks.com/blog/post/2012/10/10/Do-We-Need-The-Repository-Pattern.aspx ;)

Comment: I hadn't seen the post. Perhaps I should write a new nogginbox blog post called 'When should I use the repository pattern with an ORM'. Lots of good reasons in Sapiens Work's post about why you would. If you just want to wrap your ORM to make it testable then no. If you have multiple data sources that you want to hide, or plan to swap out your data layer later then maybe yes.

Answer (score 0):

Martin Fowler's "Patterns of Enterprise Architecture", provides the following definition for a repository:

> Mediates between the domain and data mapping layers using a collection-like interface for accessing domain objects.

A common way to implement that in C# is to have a generic `Repository<T>` class where T is a persistent object that implements `IQueryable<T>` and provides additional methods like `Add(entity)`, `Remove(entity)`.

It would be very difficult to implement without an ORM. You can make a simpler repository that takes SQL statements as WHERE conditions but it can get messy.

Numerous examples use concrete repository classes for each type with different persistence methods. But those are just disguised DAO classes.

Comment: I don't quite agree with you. Generics didn't even exist when he defined the pattern. And they are numerous examples that use in-memory collections to simulate it.

Comment: I just provided a common way to implement repositories. You can definitely simplify the implementation to use SQL statements to return and materialize objects.

Comment: Generic repositories are bad with one exception: all your repos look the same and persist anyting in the same place (ex: domain repositories storing everything in one table in serialized form). Iqueryable exposed by a repository is an anti pattern for 2 reasons: 1) It assumes that a business object is identical to the underlying data store entity, most of the time an ORM entity and 2) Iqueryable specifies HOW to build a query when that's the repo's concern. You don't tell the repository HOW to do stuff, you tell it what you want from it.

Comment: 1) The ORM technology behind the scenes is created for 1 reason - to map your business objects to the database schema. Not all solutions, especially a custom ADO data access layer can do that, but that is why repositories are so common for Entity Framework/NHibernate. Solutions like document or object databases allow you to persist the state of the business objects without any mappings. 2). As I mentioned above, a repository is a collection-like mediator. So you can use LINQ-to-DBProvider just like you would use LINQ-to-Objects to IEnumerable/List collections in memory.

Comment: Abstracting every single query is difficult because you might need different fetch paths in different scenarios for the same object graph. And it would make repositories become DAO objects.

Comment: Abstracting every single query is the whole purpose of the repostiory pattern. Without doing so you get a leaky abstraction, which means that you could just have used your OR/M interfaces directly. If you are deciding that you should use the repository pattern make sure that you do it properly. As for the pattern itself there are two camps: Those that combine it with the specification pattern and those that use the more verbose approach (`GetUserByEmail`).

Comment: I strongly discourage anyone from using `IQuerable<T>` in their repository implementations because of: a) there is no complete Linq To Sql provider available for it. b) Most providers have their own customizations (like the `Include` method in EF). You do not truly abstract away the data source if you decide to expose `IQueryable`, so why use the pattern then?

Comment: @DmitryStarosta 1) ORM is created to map objects to relational tables. DTOs are objects too. The more complex the business object the diferent it will be from the tables it would be stored in. Simply put, the fact that in some cases a business object is identical to some table is just a coincidence or you're modelling your domain according to the db structure. ORM just creates the illusion of an object oriented database. Nothing to do with busines behavior. 2) I wouldn't use LINQ anywhere in a Repository contract. Besides, one of the benefits of the pattern is that the rest of the app ...

Comment: ... doesn't need to care about what storage is used and how it's used. A properly applied Repository pattern means I can write the ENTIRE application (business and UI) without writing a single line of code for persistence. Basically, the app should work perfectly using just stubs, mocks or in memory repos. Switching storage from in memory to a RDBMS (ORM or not) or to a remote service should mean that I have to write a different repository implementation. The repo interface stays the same.

Comment: A repository needs to return entities, not DTOs. Otherwise, it would be an data access object. If DTOs are being used, the repository implementation should hide them.

Comment: There are a lot of different IQueryable providers to different storage technologies, and IQueryable is super easy to mock in tests by using inMemoryList.AsQueryable(). Neither of the points conflict with anything I had said.